# Unity 2D - Can't Drag, Move, or Rescale anything

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the latest version of unity, and for some reason I am unable to do anything with something on screen. I have selected the tools and all, it just does not work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPMyD.png

Comment: Switch to the SceneView ;) the Game view basically only shows what the Cameras are Rendering ..

Answer (score 2):

You are in the "Game view". You need to switch to the "Scene view".

[image]

Ctrl + 1 or "Window - General - Scene" if you don't see the tab "Scene".